# Xcode 9.1 simulator stay in front button missing?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

There used to be a button called "stay in front" in older versions of ios simulater. I used this often, but in recent updates it seems to be removed. Is there a any way to activate this feature ?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/sYXDM] 
new window menu

[image: old window menu]  old window menu

Comment: We removed this intentionally.

Comment: Will it come back?

Comment: Apple policy is not to comment on future releases. If this feature is important to you please do file a request at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for removing this useful feature Apple, now every time I run the app I must find simulator and bring it to front manually

Comment: @AlexMcG I kill the occasional spider and read my kids a bedtime story so "absolutely useless" is a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: hehe killing spiders leads to more bugs

Comment: Dont' u guys know? You are suppose to put this simulator at touchbar. so it is always there. yes, my comment does not make sense at all. just like apple's decision.

Comment: this feature is sadly still missing in Xcode 12

Answer (score 46):

The option "Stay In Front" for simulator staying on top of all windows is removed from Xcode9 update. Many developers will heartbreak with this including me, but we all know apple has no mercy on developers, and this is not the new thing, we all experience this kind of many things from years. Sorry mates its truth to digest.

Comment: Did you file a bug report requesting this feature be brought back? Number of bug reports is an important factor in prioritization. So far I don't think anyone has bothered so it can't be that important. You can work around it with Command+Tab or arranging windows on-screen.

Comment: @russbishop Any idea on why removing such a unobtrusive feature became a priority in the first place?

Comment: @JoseBrowne from Xcode 9 it support multiple simulators at a time, so i believe the feature removed because of multiple simulators lie on the mac screen hiding the bottom windows, but as developers we need the feature on first priority

Comment: I will file a bug report to bring this feature back as it is quite useful in minimizing clickety clickety window management

Comment: @jcpennypincher please do it, i already filed one. Lets see atleast someone form apple would respond. All we have to do is, just wait! thanks.

Comment: It may be that because XCode 9 can support multiple simulators and devices at the same time, that they removed it because they would have to enable all simulators on top at once, or have a separate always on top for each simulator. Maybe this will be in XCode 13 or 15... :(

Answer (score 14):

Made a [report](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=36324703). Please support it, as we all need this functionality

Update 11.01.2018:
Apple closed it as duplicate with no further info. Thank you, Apple.

Update 26.09.2020
They brought it back in Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

Thank you, Apple!

Answer (score 4):

#### Update your Xcode to : `v12.0.1`

---

[image]

Comment: interesting: why they don't put this option near to "Bring All to Front"